# Installing local package to PyCharm

Tags: python, package, installation, pycharm

I am trying to install a custom Python 3 package into PyCharm.  The package comes with a setup.py file.  In PyCharm's Project Interpreter settings, I tried adding the local directory (according to [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)) which contains the setup.py file but the package is not registering when I reload the list of available packages to install.  Tried adding the directory which includes the .egg file but to no avail either.  How am I supposed to install custom packages?  Is there a command line I could use instead for PyCharm?

Using PyCharm Pro v3.4 on OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up setting up a virtual environment (using virtualenvwrapper), installing the python packages there, and then pointing the Project Interpreter within PyCharm to the python version sitting within the virtual environment.